# Why string is not modifiable in new compilers

Tags: c++, c, string, compiler-construction

In days of Turbo C/C++ you could easily modify strings like in

```
char * str = "Hello";
str[1] = '1'; //it will make it H1llo;
```

Now they are stored in `.bss` and you are not allowed to modify them directly. Why? Doesn't this make modifying a string difficult?

Is there any quick fix (but without side-effects) for it? I can `strdup()` like functions, but directly modifying strings was real fun.

Comment: @Mihai: also Turbo lived in past. Poor we.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you observe, you're not allowed by the Standard to modify the string literals content, and modern compiler's/OSs arrange memory permissions accordingly.

The reason is that the compiler may see a literal used in many places in the code, for example:

```
in x.cpp:    std::cerr << "Error" << separator << msg << '\n';

in y.cpp:    if (x == "Error") ...

in z.cpp:    q = "StackOverflowError";
```

It's very desirable to avoid having all those string literals appear separately in the executable image and loaded process memory; instead, the compiler may arrange a single memory region containing "StackOverFlowError\0" and use pointers to the relevant start character (whether the 'S' or 'E') at the points of use.

If you were allowed to modify the value - perhaps deciding that you wanted x.cpp to display "Alert" instead of "Error", it could unintentionally break the code from y.cpp and z.cpp too.

> Is there a quick fix?

Well, if depends what you think's broken.  If you mean a way to modify the string literals, then no... that's undefined behaviour for the reasons explained above, and the memory protection mechanisms will vary with the OS etc..  If you mean to be able to modify textual data in a similar way, then yes: `char* s = "abc";` puts `s` on the stack, but it points to that .bss data as you've observed.  If you instead write:

```
char s[] = "abc";
```

Then `s` is still on the stack but is now an array with space for 4 character, the string literal is still in the .bss, but whenever that line runs it copies from the latter to the former, after which you're able to modify the stack-based copy ala `s[1] = 'x';`.

Of course, putting your data into a `std::string` is normally a better approach.

Comment: Agree with your answer but confused with compilers behavior.

Comment: "you're not allowed by the Standard to modify the string literals content" -- That is not correct; the Standard does not disallow modifying string literals, it simply fails to specify what will happen if you do  -- which means that a program that does so is not a conforming program, but the standard doesn't require programs to conform, and most don't. There are implementations that do allow modifying string literals (one is provided by the market leader), and the flagship program of a company I consult for has contained such code for the last 17 years or so.

Comment: @JimBalter: ignoring the "not allowed" versus "not disallow" business... it's undefined, which is not just the Standard "fail[ing] to specify what will happen if you do", it's saying that implementations aren't required to specify it either - though certainly they may.  Which compiler are you talking about?  Visual C++ says it's undefined at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx.  I'm 99.999% sure it's not implementation defined for GCC.  Hard to see how any other compiler could be considered the market leader, but I'm all ears....

Comment: *which is not just* -- yes, it is. *it's saying that implementations aren't required to specify it either* -- implementations aren't required to send you a million dollars either ... that the standard doesn't require them to isn't interesting. All the standard does is define what it takes to be a conforming implementation or program.

Comment: *Visual C++* -- um, "In some cases, identical string literals can be "pooled" to save space in the executable file. In string-literal pooling, the compiler causes all references to a particular string literal to point to the same location in memory, instead of having each reference point to a separate instance of the string literal. /GF enables string pooling." *I'm all ears...* -- it seems to be your eyes you're having trouble with.

Comment: *Visual C++ says it's undefined* -- it's saying what the standard says, then it has an MS-specific section ... this really isn't hard to follow or understand if you're willing to. From the /GF page: */GF pools strings as read-only. If you try to modify strings under /GF, an application error occurs.* -- guess what: if you don't specify /GF, you *won't* get an application error.

Comment: *ignoring the "not allowed" versus "not disallow" business...* -- It's common for people to ignore that, but understanding it is vital to understanding what the C standard is for and what powers it has.

Comment: @JimBalter: that's hilarious mate... you're clearly getting off on lecturing me about all this, while defending code that relies on assuming "if you try to modify strings under /GF an application error occurs" also implies that if you don't use /GF it's ok. And you think that's not undefined behaviour you're relying on. Ever heard of "denying the antecedent"? Just try it with VS2010 C++ project: it crashes without string pooling. Better stick on VC6 or whatever ;-).  Thanks for the laughs - couldn't make this stuff up! And thanks for being so rude to boot.

Comment: "Just try it with VS2010 C++ project: it crashes without string pooling." -- because the /Gf flag has been removed there. "And thanks for being so rude to boot." -- Hypocritical much? You're amused by your own intellectual dishonesty, but it bores me. Bye.

Comment: @JimBalter: the /GF- flag has not been removed... it still affects string pooling, but doesn't prevent access violation.  A very good bye indeed....

Comment: @JimBalter: you switched from so many mentions of /GF to /Gf just once - excuse me for thinking it a typo.  Anyway, /Gf was deprecated even in VS2003/VC++6, and more recent VC++ versions generate access violations with or without pooling.  It's just not an option in current C++.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying string literals is **undefined behaviour** under C standard.

The fact that you could do it with older compilers does not imply that it's legal in all compilers, they merely used to be more permissive and did not protect you from writing this memory area.

You can do:

```
char str[] = "Hello";
str[1] = '1';
```

This will create a mutable array of `char` and initialise it *with a copy of string literal's value* (including a `\0` terminator).

Comment: In Visual Studio atlest it won't.

Comment: @ss7don if that were true, it would be enough reason not to use that particular version of VS.

Comment: @ss7don Here, "Hello" is an initializer for `str`; `str` is not const or a string literal, so it's writable.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the "why" question. The trivial answer that others already mentioned is "it's undefined behavior". Which means that the standard allows the compiler to do whatever the compiler wants.

But why is it undefined behavior? The reason is that in large software projects you can often end up with thousands of duplicated strings, maybe you have a macro that crashes the program if it detects some inconsistency and prints out a message. This macro is repeated in thousands of places and prints the same message every time. If strings were modifiable, the message would have to be duplicated thousands of time in the final binary. To prevent that lots of linkers perform deduplication of strings in the binary which means that if you have `printf("foo\n"); printf("foo\n");` in your program both `"foo\n"` strings will be in the same memory location. Now imagine that you have: `char *foo = "foo\n"; printf("foo\n");` The compiler might think that it can deduplicate the string and somewhere else in your program you do `*foo = 'b';`. Now the printf will be incorrect. To prevent this, modifying string literals is undefined behavior and modern compilers will use that fact to deduplicate strings (on a much more advanced level than my examples here) and hopefully generate the program in such a way that modifying string literals will crash.